# How to implement a RecycleView as a partial view that can be updated by a button press?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm currently working on a project that pulls data from an API and exports a fully formatted excel document using python. I have all of the back end code working now (pulling the data, building lists and exporting the excel document) I'm now just working on a Kivy UI for the end user to be able to use. (I'm very new to Kivy and I'm learning it as I go)

My issue is currently on my second page. On this page they have the ability to 
select an event type and then search by a date range to see all of the possible events they can select from. I've got the lists setup but now I want to be able to display this data on the right side of the screen. On the left side they have all of the buttons and drop downs for narrowing down their search and the right side should just be some sort of selectable list.

I would like the user to be able to choose their search criteria then hit a button that goes out and pulls all of the events and displays them in the list. They should be able to update their criteria and then hit the search button again to update the results.

I was looking to use RecycleView but all of the examples I keep finding are where the RecycleView is the widget being returned in the build so it takes up the entire screen. I'm currently using Screen Managers with individual screens and have the screen setup into two different BoxLayouts. I want the right BoxLayout to contain the RecycleView.

Is what I'm going after realistic for RecycleView? Does it need to have it's own screen and it's own class?

Here is an example I was messing with for testing but I'm not sure how to implement something similar into my own app.

1. How is self.data related to root.text? Is self.data the entire list?
2. How do I have multiple columns?
3. If I want to update the data with the click of a button, do I need to use the "refresh_from_data(*largs, **kwargs)"? How does that work?

If someone can help steer me in the right direction I can figure it out. I think this example might give enough to work off of.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 1.10.0
#: import Popup kivy.uix.popup

<MessageBox>:
    title: 'Popup Message Box'
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 400

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: root.message
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            text: 'OK'
            on_press: root.dismiss()

<RecycleViewRow>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Label:
        text: root.text
    Button:
        text: 'Show'
        on_press: app.root.message_box(root.text)

<MainScreen>:
    viewclass: 'RecycleViewRow'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'                    
                    ''')

class MessageBox(Popup):
    message = StringProperty()

class RecycleViewRow(BoxLayout):
    text = StringProperty()

class MainScreen(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'text': "Button " + str(x), 'id': str(x)} for x in range(3)]

    def message_box(self, message):
        p = MessageBox()
        p.message = message
        p.open()
        print('test press: ', message)

class TestApp(App):
    title = "RecycleView Direct Test"

    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. How is self.data related to root.text? Is self.data the entire list?

The `root.text` of every `RecycleViewRow` gets populated from the `"text"` key of every item in the `self.data`. `self.data` is the entire list's data.

> 2. How do I have multiple columns?

If the `RecycleViewRow` widget gets created with multiple columns (e.g. a horizontal `BoxLayout` with many labels), then the list has many columns.
Don't forget that the list is just many widgets of its `viewclass`.

> 3. If I want to update the data with the click of a button, do I need to use the "refresh_from_data(*largs, **kwargs)"? How does that work?

Yes. This just tells to the `RecycleView` to re-read its data (`self.data` in this example) and re-populate the list.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. How do I implement the RecycleView as part of a screen? I want the RecycleView to be a part of the screen (half) but not the whole screen. How do I have a Screen that has a button on the left side to refresh the data and the RecycleView on the right? The example I posted has the mainclass inheriting from RecycleView but mine is a screen.Also how did you know about the text key? I find the documentation at https://kivy.org/ to be very confusing. Is there a solid video that explains these RecycleVIews piece by piece? I can't find anythign anywhere on them.

Comment: You can put a horizontal `BoxLayout` in your main class (your screen).  Inside that `BoxLayout`, you can add two children. The `RecycleView` and a `Button` for the reset.   As for the keys, the way they work is this.  Every item in the data list is a row.   Every key in the item is a value of an attribute of the `viewclass` widget.  Yes, the documentation is lacking, but all the stuff is somewhere there.  Googling around can find you everything else...;o)